# Populate ul in html with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-lists

Hi im trying to populate ul in html with JSON, i have tried many solutions from this site, but im not having much luck, any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated. Thanks

my code :

```
<script>
$.getJSON('/simplepie/round/alltables.json', function (data) {
var o = null;
var myArray = new Array();
document.open(); 
for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
{ 
    o = data[i];
    myArray.push('<li>' + o.title + '</li>');
    //document.write(o.source + " <br>" + o.description + "<br>") ;
    myArray.push(o.source);
    makeUL(o.source);
} 

//document.close();
// document.write('Latitude: ' + data.id + '\nLongitude: ' + data.title + '\nCountry: ' + data.description);

function makeUL(array) {
    var list = document.createElement('ul');
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
        list.appendChild(item);
    }


  return list;
  }

});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<ul id="ct"></ul>
</body>
```

JSON structure

```
[{"id":"1","source":"Articles | Mail Online",
"time_date":"1422720360",
"title":"Rouhani accuses Iranian hardliners of ",
"description":"DUBAI, Jan 31 (Reuters) - Iranian President Hassan Rouhani",
"link":"http:\/\/www.dailymail.co.uk\/wires\/reuters\/article-2934402\/Rouhani-accuses-Iranian-hardliners-cheering-atom-talks.html?ITO=1490&amp;ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_campaign=1490",
"image":"http:\/\/i.dailymail.co.uk\/i\/pix\/m_logo_154x115px.png"}]
```

Comment: you're throwing away the return value of `makeUL`. You are not adding it anywhere to the DOM. so how come you expect it to show up? a mind-reading computer would be pretty scary I think…

Comment: thanks for the reply this is my first attempt with html / javascipt any suggestions .

Comment: What is your desired result? from the code it's unclear if you want to make your list out of the `title` key of the `source` key. Also, makeUL is meant to operate on an array, but you're calling it on every item of your JSON. Lastly, please provide an example of the JSON structure.

Comment: hi  json structure added, the desired result is to show all the columns from the json in a list, i am experimenting so i can show the title first, but ideally i want to show all of them. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your loop with this:

Get a handle on your List since its already in your body `<ul id="ct"></ul>`:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("ct");
```

Then create the li using javascript and append it to your list:

```
for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
{ 
    var obj = data[i];
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.title));
    ul.appendChild(li);     
}
```

There is no need for your MakeUL function

Here is a JS Fiddle to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/6nrx1zkj/

Comment: hi loanburger, im still not getting the items in the list, any suggestions ?

Comment: I added a JS fiddle to my anser for you to demonstrate it if you were still having issues.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to loanburgers solution, i got the code working The o variable needed to be declared.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("ct");

 for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ )
 { 
    var o = data[i];
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.title));
    ul.appendChild(li);    
 }                   
});
```